# View close/reopen votes without 3k rep

Tags: script, questions, closing

### Preview

[image]

### About

This script enables you to view the close/reopen votes on a post without unlocking the [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege unlocked at 3000 reputation.

Powered by Stack Exchange API.

#### Download

| Version | Minified | Unminified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Version 1.0](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/CloseReopenVoteViewer/v1.0) | [install](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CloseReopenVoteViewer/v1.0/script.min.user.js) | [install](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CloseReopenVoteViewer/v1.0/script.user.js) |

#### Browser Support

| IE | Chrome | Firefox | Safari | Edge | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔️ 6+ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ 5.1+ | ✔️ 12.1+ | ✔️ 11.5+ |

#### Additional Information

| #### License | #### Suggestions/Issues |
| --- | --- |
| [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE) | Suggestions and issues should be raised as an answer in this post |

---

Languages/libraries used: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

If the user has <3K, the "Close" link does nothing.

It would be better if the button was disabled for <3K users or led to a dialog explaining that the user needed 3K reputation to cast close and re-open votes.

Comment: The link is only shown to <3K users.